# How to fix 'invalid syntax error' in tensorwatch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

After I installed the tensorwatch package, I imported it but here was an error. Some details are shown below, could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

```py
import tensorwatch

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\33574\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-d0d9e150d101>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorwatch

  File "C:\Users\33574\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorwatch\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .watcher_client import WatcherClient

  File "C:\Users\33574\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorwatch\watcher_client.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .zmq_wrapper import ZmqWrapper

  File "C:\Users\33574\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorwatch\zmq_wrapper.py", line 16
    _thread:Thread = None
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your python version is 3.5. 
It may work in Ubuntu 16.06 LTS but I have the same problem on windows

Comment: This line `_thread:Thread = None` doesn't look to me like valid Python. What is the bit up to the colon supposed to do? It looks like you are trying to declare the variable type. You can't do that in Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've searched on github, and gotten the answer. Github user mtobeiyf said, in Tensorwatch source code, I found that there are some syntaxes not supported by Python 3.5.2, including such typing: _thread:Thread = None and format string: print(f"{}").
The solution is switching to Python 3.6+.
I think the README should point out this, since Ubuntu comes with Python 3.5.2 by default.